# Malware infected website

Tags: php, javascript, malware

I have the following problem:
The website I made for a friend has been infected with malware. When I tried to clean it, by replacing files that I found to be different to the ones I uploaded, with my original files, after a short time, the files were different again. The file permissions are all 644, and the folders 755. It is as if the one who infected the files has access to change them whenever I change them back. Can anyone help me since I am very new to this kind of problems?

Comment: Yes, you have some kind of security hole that allows attackers to overwrite files. Could be anything of a thousand different possibilities.

Comment: Ha ve you changed the passwords?

Comment: The friend I made the site for, has contacted the server providers and they changed the log in data. I realize it can be a number of different things, and that there must be a security hole somewhere - what I don't know is if the hole is the problem of the server providers, or if it was somehow generated through my code... I am not sure if anyone could help about that, but any insight would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: **report this to your webhost immediately!** Secondly **change all of your relevant passwords!**

That being done, there are a few possible causes:

- Your parent webhost has been compromised, in which case there is nothing you can do except move to a better host.
- Your website contains a vulnerability that is being picked-up by kiddies with their vuln-scanners. Be sure to audit your code to ensure that no user action can result in your website's filesystem being touched inappropriately; also check for SQL injection avenues.
- Your website uses a widely-distributed application, such as WordPress, that has not been patched - this is a major problem.
- Your own PC has been compromised and ne'erdowells have used a keylogger or other software to discover your FTP or SSH account details, and are abusing your website. Run a local scan and audit everything to ensure your bank account is being raided either.

Comment: One of the causes you mentioned I can dismiss immediately - the widely-distributed application one, since I did all of the code myself. The rest I will check and see what can be done. So far your answer is closest to what I needed to know, and thank you very much.

Comment: I have one question - what kind of vulnerabilities do you think of in the second cause you mentioned? I have no idea what kind of code can lead to accessing my filesystem by others...

Comment: File upload scripts, for example. Someone could upload a PHP file that is saved to a public folder; when accessed directly it would be executed on the server providing an attacker with complete control. If you dont have anything like this on your site then your webhost was probably compromised and you're not at fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again. There is no uploading of files on the site so I guess the problem really is with the server providers.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a code-related problem. This isn't the place for your question.

But: It's likely that a program is running on your server and re-infecting the files. I'd recommend either taking it to a professional malware removal service, or (my preference) burning the server in a fire and allowing a new server to rise from the ashes. Then install an AV suite on the new server.

Comment: The fact that chmod permissions are being respected means it's likely a Linux server, probably a shared webhost. @MarkoCakic probably isn't in a position to install AV on the server (not that server AV is effective anyway...).

Comment: Its not a code related problem but its a genuine question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions
States that you should only ask problems uniquely experienced by programmers.